# How to minimize the complexity of this code ,by avoiding it to traverse all the jenkins job(lets say 5000 jobs?)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, hudson

I'm changing my jenkins job's SCM url from, lets say `gitlab` to `github` by using Groovy script. Is there any way to minimize the complexity of this code ?

I have used `Jenkins.instance.items.each {}` which traverses through all the jobs in my jenkins

```
import hudson.plugins.git.*
import jenkins.*
import jenkins.model.*

def modifyGitUrl(url) {
    def newurl = url.replace("source", "destination")
    return newurl
                }

    def modifyGitID(credentialsId) {
    def newID = ("Jenkins User ID")
    return newID
                }

     Jenkins.instance.items.each {
         if(it.name == "expected name"){
             if (it.scm instanceof GitSCM) {
                def oldScm = it.scm
                def newUserRemoteConfigs = oldScm.userRemoteConfigs.collect {
                new UserRemoteConfig(modifyGitUrl(it.url), it.name, it.refspec, modifyGitID(it.credentialsId))
                    }
                def newScm = new GitSCM(newUserRemoteConfigs, oldScm.branches, oldScm.doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations,
                             oldScm.submoduleCfg, oldScm.browser, oldScm.gitTool, oldScm.extensions)
                    it.scm = newScm 
                    it.save()    
                  }
                  }
                }
```

Comment: if you need just one item by name: `Jenkins.get().itemMap['expected name']`

Comment: maybe https://codereview.stackexchange.com  is better for this kind of question